# Custom attributes not shown in user profile in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have added custom attributes during Sign-up and added the same in the application claim in Azure AD B2C management portal. 
I was expecting these custom attributes to be added as part of the user profile who signed-up using their social identity provider.

Could someone help me on getting these custom attributes in the user profile screen of Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides creating the custom attribute, **you need to add it to your policy's Attributes**. Optionally you can also configure the attribute as an application claim.

You do this in the "Sign-up attributes" or "Edit profile attributes" section while editing you policy.

**Keep in mind this is different from adding the attribute to your application claims**.

While the former shows it in the UI allowing the user to edit the attribute, the latter sends the value of that attribute to the application in the id_token.

See the [use a custom attribute in your policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr#use-a-custom-attribute-in-your-sign-up-policy) documentation for more info.

It is also worth noting that at this time, **custom attributes do not show up in the Azure portal's Users & Groups blade**. As an admin, you can only view and update those [using the Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet). You can request this as a feature in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](http://aka.ms/aadb2cuv)

Comment: Hi Saca, thank you for responding to my question. I have added a custom attribute named "skypeId" in the "User Attributes" section of B2C tenant. Then the same attribute was included in the policy and am getting it as part of the response to the request application (along with token) as application claims. I was expecting that this attribute is added to the user profile and shown in the Azure portal where we can see the newly signed-in user's profile. But i could not see this field. I followed the instruction from the docs. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Attributes (in general) are only shown in sign UP and edit profile, and only if you select them. There's no place for attributes to be shwon in sign IN.

Comment: I suppose then my understanding is incorrect. Any custom attribute is not added to the user profile and will not be shown in the Azure management portal. Is that correct?

Comment: Custom attributes do not show anywhere in the Azure Management portal at this time.

Comment: @Jeeva, can you please flag this question as answered please, or further clarify what else is needed here?